# Application switcher's (compiz) thumbnails not working in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, compiz, application-switcher, thumbnails

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I somehow cannot get compiz effects to work. especially application switcher's thumbnails - I only get the icons and I think that changing the options do not change the behavior of the switcher.

It did work like a charm in 11.04

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Alt + ` (Grave accent, next to the 1 key).

Do not bother messing around with Compiz effects on Ubuntu 12.04. Most of them don't really work well with Unity.